# Can selected elements be rotated in opposite directions?

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to rotate e.g. the left selected edge counter clockwise and the right one clockwise?

[image]

Comment: You could mirror them

Comment: @gandalf3 I want to adjust some parts of a mesh where the mirror modifier is already applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general **no**. But for cases where the mesh/armature is symmetrical. Then *X-Mirror* from the *Options Tab* can be enabled.

[image]